# Fuzzy Logic for Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy

I tried to program it in VBA, but then I noted it was not possible with this programming language. Then I was searching in Google, but I don't find any answer about implementing Fuzzy Logic, in special the trapezoidal model, in any art of form of Excel (Sheets formels or VBA).

Do you have any idea, if this logic can be implemented or used in Excel?

This is what I mean about Fuzzy Models:
http://www.dma.fi.upm.es/recursos/aplicaciones/logica_borrosa/web/fuzzy_inferencia/funpert_en.htm

Comment: Sounds like you need a list of X values and you could manage the output with IF to meet the requirements of lower and upper bounds (a and b)

Comment: Thanks! I manage to create the Fuzzy Inputs and Fuzzy rules in VBA. What I don´t get is the Fuzzy Output, somehow I miss the variable X for them.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just tried for fun but something like this could be a start. The formula to get Y values is just IFS:

```
=IF(OR(A10<$B$3;A10>$B$6);0;IF(A10<$B$4;(A10-$B$3)/($B$4-$B$3);IF(A10<$B$5;1;($B$6-A10)/($B$6-$B$5))))
```